# Show variable's value in output of time command in zsh

Tags: zsh, time

I want to measure runtime of my program for a series on input variables (I am using zsh):

```
for i in {1..3} ; do time sleep $i ; done
```

The output is

```
sleep $i  0,00s user 0,00s system 0% cpu 1,003 total
sleep $i  0,00s user 0,00s system 0% cpu 2,003 total
sleep $i  0,00s user 0,00s system 0% cpu 3,002 total
```

But I expect it to be

```
sleep 1  0,00s user 0,00s system 0% cpu 1,003 total
sleep 2  0,00s user 0,00s system 0% cpu 2,003 total
sleep 3  0,00s user 0,00s system 0% cpu 3,002 total
```

**How do I get `time` to print the actual command with all the variables being substituted with their value?**

---

I already tried running the program in a sub-shell, which did not change the output as expected:

```
for i in {1..3} ; do time (sleep $i) ; done
```

Since my program produces own output to stdout and stderr, I don't see a way to simply prepend all the parameters (there are some more than just `i`) like, for instance:

```
for i in {1..3} ; do echo -n "i=$i --> " ; time sleep $i ; done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `time` is a keyword that can act on a compound command. (More precisely, it acts on a pipeline.) You can write something like

```
time (i=$(($(/bin/echo 1) + 1)); sleep $i)
```

and the time zsh spends parsing the command, including calculating `$i`, is part of what is timed.

One solution is to use the `time` external command instead. That acts on an external command, so the shell expansions aren't part of what is timed. With GNU time (which doesn't print the command by default):

```
% for i in {1..3} ; do =time -f '%C  %Us user %Ss system %P cpu %e total' sleep $i ; done
sleep 1  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.00 total
sleep 2  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 2.00 total
sleep 3  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 3.00 total
```

Another solution is to print the command yourself. Note that the code below prints the command text before the command's output if any.

```
% for i in {1..3} ; do echo -n "sleep $i"; (TIMEFMT=${TIMEFMT#%J}; time sleep $i); done
sleep 1  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.004 total
sleep 2  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 2.004 total
sleep 3  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 3.004 total
```

Another solution is to activate command tracing.

```
% for i in {1..3} ; do (TIMEFMT=${TIMEFMT#%J}; set -x; time sleep $i); done     
+zsh:14> sleep 1
  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.004 total
+zsh:14> sleep 2
  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 2.004 total
+zsh:14> sleep 3
  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 3.005 total
```

Another solution is to inject the text you want into the time format.

```
% for i in {1..3} ; do (TIMEFMT="${${:-sleep $i}//\%/%%}${TIMEFMT#%J}"; time sleep $i); done
sleep 1  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.004 total
sleep 2  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 2.004 total
sleep 3  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 3.004 total
```

Another solution is to construct the simplest shell command possible and `eval` it. Since this involves `eval`, be careful if the command might contain shell special characters.

```
% for i in {1..3} ; do eval "time sleep $i"; done                  
sleep 1  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.002 total
sleep 2  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 2.005 total
sleep 3  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 3.004 total
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
$ for i in {1..3} ; do eval "time sleep $i:q"; done
sleep 1  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.004 total
sleep 2  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 2.003 total
sleep 3  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 3.002 total
```

(the `:q` is not necessary in this case when `$i` contains only digits, but would be in the general case when wanting to pass the contents of `$i` as a literal argument to some command).

You could also always replace `%J` (which expands to the job's name¹) with whatever text you want in `$TIMEFMT`:

```
for i in {1..3}; do
  TIMEFMT="sleep $i: %U user %S system %P cpu %*E total"
  time sleep $i
done
```

(bearing in mind that if `%` is to be included in that text, it should be escaped as `%%`)

---

<sup>¹ In reality, that's not really the job's name. You'll find for instance that in `time sleep 1 | sleep 2` where the whole pipeline is the job, `time` gives you two lines, one for each part of the pipeline.</sup>